# Can I use GPS sensors in a country (India) that doesn't have its own GPS Sattelites?

Tags: gps

I am living in India. I want to work on Arduino Projects with GPS Modules. But only a few countries like US, Russia, China etc. have their own GPS satellites. India is working on it. So I am hesitating to buy GPS sensors. Can I work normally with GPS modules in my country as shown in Online projects in my country ?

Comment: GPS is US only. The Russian version is called GLONASS. The EU version is called Galileo. China version is called BeiDou/COMPASS (this one only works in and around china). PS the 'G' in GPS stands for Global, to indicate it works around the globe/world.

Comment: GPS - anyone can use it anywhere that it works. Not so good nearer poles. Best choice for India. 
GLONASS - also can be used by anyone. Works best in Nortthern areas- satellites are in very elliptical orbits where they "hand high and slow" over top of northern hemisphere and are "kow and fast"in southern.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the countries listed has their own *satnav system*. GPS satellites cover the *entire world* and the US government allows *anyone* with a GPS receiver to use it, regardless of where on or above the surface they are located.

[image]